# Devise Sending Welcome Email

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, devise

I have a devise model called `members` i am using devise confirmable. Upon confirm i want to send a welcome email to the User

```
class Member < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable, :confirmable

  # Methods

  # Override devise confirm! message
  def confirm!
    welcome_email
    super
  end

  # Private Methods
  private

  def welcome_email
    MemberMailer.welcome_email(self).deliver
  end

end
```

My MemberMailer resides in `mailers/brands/member_mailer.rb`

```
class Brands::MemberMailer < ApplicationMailer

  # Send Welcome Email once Member confirms the account
  def welcome_email(member)
    @member = member
    mail(to: @member.email, subject: "Welcome to Skreem! Now you Rock!")
  end
end
```

But upon confirming through the mail Link the `confirm!` is not being **overridden** and I am not getting any error or email.

Comment: https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Use-custom-mailer check this link

Comment: @uzaif has this changed since?

Comment: Try changing `MemberMailer.welcome_email(self).deliver` to `Brands::MemberMailer.welcome_email(self).deliver`

Comment: thanks @Pavan that worked with dkp's answer

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Add this to your `Member` model:

```
def after_confirmation
  welcome_email
end
```

For more info check [**`after_confirmation`**](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/plataformatec/devise/Devise/Models/Confirmable:after_confirmation)

@Pavan thanks for pointing this.

Your `welcome_email` should be:

```
def welcome_email
  Brands::MemberMailer.welcome_email(self).deliver
end
```

Comment: Does this run only once in a case where you are also using the reconfirmable module to re-confirm users when they update their email?