# Ruby on Rails - Devise - Send sign up confirmation email on action other than usual sign up

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, devise-confirmable, email-confirmation

Using Devise, how can I send confirmation email (identical to signup email) on first password update (or on an action other than usual sign up)?

Comment: You can use the [after_confirmation](https://www.rubydoc.info/github/plataformatec/devise/Devise/Models/Confirmable:after_confirmation) devise method. Check this good example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36597212/devise-sending-welcome-email)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did it by adding a condition to `create` method in `confirmations_controller.rb`

```
def create
  self.resource = resource_class.send_confirmation_instructions(resource_params)
  yield resource if block_given?

  if successfully_sent?(resource)
    respond_with({}, location: after_resending_confirmation_instructions_path_for(resource_name))
  else
    if <condition> then
     User.find_by_email(resource.email).send_confirmation_instructions
     respond_with({}, location: after_resending_confirmation_instructions_path_for(resource_name))
    else
      respond_with(resource)
    end
  end
end
```